# Extending $1$-forms on $\mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \{(0, 0, 1) \}$ to $\mathbb{S}^2$ in a smooth manner

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

> Consider in $\mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \{N\}$ (where $N$ is the north pole) the $1$-forms $\omega, \eta$ which with respect to the stereographical
> projection from the north pole have the following local expressions: $$\omega = \mathrm{d} x, \eta = \mathrm{d} x \wedge \mathrm{d} y$$
>
> Do they have smooth extensions to the north pole?

As I understand it, once we identify in the obvious manner the tangent spaces of $\mathbb{S}^2$ with affine subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (that is, for $p \in \mathbb{S}^2$, $T_{p} \mathbb{S}^2 = p^{\perp}$) , the $1$-forms $\mathrm{d} x$ and $\mathrm{d} y$ with respect to the stereographical projection from the north pole are just the restrictions of the differential forms $\mathrm{d} r^1$ and $\mathrm{d} r^2$ to the tangent spaces of the sphere, where I'm defining $\mathrm{d} r^i(p)(e_j) = \delta_{ij} $ (the standard basis differential forms on $\mathbb{R}^3$). So of course they have smooth extensions to the north pole.

But this feels too easy so I'm thinking maybe I'm not understanding the exercise correctly. What did I do wrong here, how should I proceed?

Comment: If you take the other stereographical projection, how do they pull back? I never worked this out.

Comment: $dx$ and $dy$ are the differentials of the stereographic coordinates; they aren't related to the ambient coordinates $r^i$ in such a simple way. In fact, both $\omega$ and $\eta$ have singularities at $N$.

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman Up to a constant factor depending on convention, the transition function between stereographic coordinates from antipodal points is $\psi(\vec{x})=\vec{x}/\|x\|^2$.

Comment: @Kajelad how do they have singularities at $N$? i computed the transition matrices in the other stereographical projection but still don't see what singularities it has

Comment: Both will have singularities at $0$ in the new coordinates due to the $1/\|x\|^2$ terms, For $\omega$, there's an even simpler argument: the integral of any smooth 2-form over a compact manifold is finite, but (independent of extension) the integral of $\omega$ over $S^2$ diverges.

Comment: @Kajelad I get that the projections themselves have singularities, but computing the matrix representation of their differentials with respect to both projections I don't get any $1/\|x\|^2$ terms

Comment: Oh, actually they do appear, not $\|x\|^2$, but $\|\pi_N(x)\|^4$ in some denominators. Since at $N$ and $S$ the projections vanish, we get singularities... I get it now! Thanks